# AppDistribution failed with 403 error on Xcode 15.3

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

Xcode 15.3
I'm trying to send build to TestFlight through Xcode and got this error:

> AppsService: ResponseErrors (1): Error status: 403, code:
> FORBIDDEN.OFAC_UNCLEARED, title: 'This Apple ID has not been cleared
> by sanctions.', detail: 'This Apple ID has not been cleared by
> sanctions, so it cannot access this page.', id:___

PS. I have application in ASC with this version.

In the Agreement section there are no pending agreements
[image]

Upd:
I go dive deep into Organizer logs and found these:

```
2024-03-07 00:21:01 +0000  App Store Connect team IDs for account (null) are (
    REDACTED,
    REDACTED,
    REDACTED,
    REDACTED,
    REDACTED,
    REDACTED
)
2024-03-07 00:21:02 +0000  Step failed: <IDEDistributionFetchAppRecordStep: 0x600055c6ab20>: IDEFoundation.DistributionAppRecordProviderError.appRecordRequestFailed(DVTAppStoreConnect.AppsService.Error.responseErrors(ResponseErrors (1): Error status: 403, code: FORBIDDEN.OFAC_UNCLEARED, title: 'This Apple ID has not been cleared by sanctions.', detail: 'This Apple ID has not been cleared by sanctions, so it cannot access this page.', id: REDACTED))
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up Apple developer account, I'm sure there is a new agreement that you have to accept before publishing to app store.

Comment: I thought that too, but there is no new agreements

Comment: Weird, you have the admin role right? I just uploaded an app an hour ago and it was working for me. Although I uploaded it via Transporter app.

Comment: Yes, I'm admin.

Answer (score -1):

I found problem – I use different accounts in Xcode and in ASC so I didn't see the Compliance request
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).